# Unmet dependencies when trying to install MySQL with wget

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, mysql

I am installing MySQL 8.0 in Ubuntu 20.04, but I am facing an unmet dependencies issue.

First I run the command

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb
```

it successfully downloaded the package.

Second command

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb
```

This command also successfully ran.

Third command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Fourth command

```
sudo apt install mysql-client mysql-community-server mysql-server
```

After this command I am getting these issues.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 8.0.25-1ubuntu21.04) but 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 is installed
                    Depends: mysql-community-client-plugins (= 8.0.25-1ubuntu21.04) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried with `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, and this appeared:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 8.0.25-1ubuntu20.04) but 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 is installed
                    Depends: mysql-community-client-plugins (= 8.0.25-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 8.0.25-1ubuntu20.04) but 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 is installed
                    Depends: mysql-community-client-plugins (= 8.0.25-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Comment: "many"? I see one and it has something for you to do ... did you?  and how are you trying to install it? your method does not seem to upgrade libc 1st. https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-mysql-8-on-ubuntu/ has a working method

Comment: i followed the instructions on provided link, but nothing change getting same issue.

Comment: Did you try   apt --fix-broken install

Comment: i tired but facing following issue.
Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Comment: Man, when you try `apt --fix-broken install`, you have to give sudo permissions; otherwise will never work the apt. So, give this, `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: i also tried with sudo, but not helpful.following issues occrus.        

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient21 : Depends: mysql-common (>= 8.0.25-1ubuntu20.04) but 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 is installed
                    Depends: mysql-community-client-plugins (= 8.0.25-1ubuntu20.04) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list` and `apt-cache policy mysql-common libmysqlclient21`.